# What can we say about Green's relations on a semilattice?

Tags: soft-question, order-theory, equivalence-relations, semigroups, greens-relations

*Note: This is a [soft-question](/questions/tagged/soft-question) in the flavour of, say, "what does $X$ look like?" and "Is there a description of $Y$?" - so, hopefully, it is not too broad. Let's focus on the basics if necessary.*

### The Details:

> **Definition:** A (meet/join) semilattice is a commutative, idempotent semigroup.

I prefer join semilattices (but they are isomorphic to meet semilattices.)

> **Definition ([Green's Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations)):** Let $S$ be a semigroup and $S^1$ be $S$ with an one adjoined. Then
>
> $$\begin{align}
> a\mathscr{L}b&\iff S^1a=S^1b,\\
> a\mathscr{R}b&\iff aS^1=bS^1,\\
> a\mathscr{J}b&\iff S^1aS^1=S^1bS^1,\\
> a\mathscr{H}b&\iff (a\mathscr{L}b\land a\mathscr{R}b),\\
> a\mathscr{D}b&\iff a(\mathscr{L}\circ\mathscr{R})b\\
> &\iff a(\mathscr{R}\circ\mathscr{L})b,
> \end{align}$$
>
> where $x(\rho\circ\sigma)y$ iff there is a $c$ such that $x\rho c$ and $c\sigma y$, where $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are equivalence relations.

### The Question:

> What can we say in general about Green's relations of a semilattice $L$?

### Thoughts:

Due to commutativity, $\mathscr{L}=\mathscr{R}$; this implies $\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{H}$.

According to [this (pdf)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/41789B1749144CF88F5E9240D69ADEEC/S0017089500001610a.pdf/div-class-title-congruences-and-green-s-relations-on-regular-semigroups-div.pdf), $\mathscr{J}$ is trivial.

### Context:

I'm gathering relevant theorems for an idea I have for semilattices. I can't share what that idea is but I can tell you I'm looking at $XL$ for a certain type of $X\subseteq L$, where $L$ is a semilattice of a technical nature.

Comment: $\mathscr{L} = \mathscr{R} = \mathscr{H} = \mathscr{J} = \mathscr{D}$ from commutativity

Comment: Thank you, @Jakobian. I'd accept that as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Another way to see that they are trivial is that maximal subgroups of a semilattice are one-point sets $\{x\}$, and equivalence class $[x]_\mathscr{H}$ is the maximal subgroup containing $x$, since $x$ is idempotent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since semilattices are commutative, $aS^1 = S^1a = S^1aS^1$. The last equality can be seen from $S^1aS^1 = a(S^1)^2 = aS^1$ since $S^1$ is a monoid.

Thus all the Green relations for semilattices are equal: $$\mathscr{L} = \mathscr{R} = \mathscr{J} = \mathscr{H} = \mathscr{D}.$$

Another easy way to see all of them are trivial, is that equivalence classes $[e]_\mathscr{H} = \{x : e\mathscr{H} x\}$ for an idempotent $e$ are precisely the maximal subgroups of $S$ with $e$ as the identity element (not to be confused with maximal subgroups in group theory, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_subgroup)). For two distinct idempotents $e, f\in S$ those equivalence classes don't overlap (as a group cannot have two distinct identity elements), but all elements in a semilattice are idempotent. Hence all the Green relations are trivial.